# How can I use this autofill feature from json with dynamically created inputs?

Tags: javascript, json, dynamic

I'm using this autofill function which grabs a value from the input `descricaoItem(description)`, send it to a query and fill the other input field with the `codigo(code)` value, from the database. The code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {          

            $('#descricaoItem0').change(function () {

            $.post('mandaDescricao.php',
                {
                   descricao: document.getElementById('descricaoItem0').value
                },     

                    function(data){
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        $('#codigoItem0').val(obj.codigo); 

                    });   
                });         
        });
```

This one works fine, but I want to create those inputs dynamically, when the user presses a button. Already have this function, and the inputs are created with different ID's (`descricaoItem0`, `descricaoItem1`, and so on...) which are related with (`codigoItem0`, `codigoItem1`,...). But, with these inputs dynamically created I can't find a way to use the above function.

Could you please, help me? I don't want to copy and paste this function 'till `descricaoItem20`.

Comment: If you create the `input`s dynamically, you have to make sure you add the event handling after the `input`s are created and rendered to the DOM. I can't say for sure that is the issue, but it is something to look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your event assigner in a function!
Every time a new input is added, fire this function and pass the correct id number.

```js
function assignOnChangeToInput(id) {
  $('#descricaoItem' + id).change(function() {

    $.post('mandaDescricao.php', {
        descricao: document.getElementById('descricaoItem' + id).value
      },

      function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#codigoItem' + id).val(obj.codigo);

      });
  });
});
}
```

Comment: This simple solution worked like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: I gave it, but it won't count since my reputation is still low.

Comment: Well come back when it is. Help others where you can!

Comment: Will do! Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a JSON object that consists of an Array of Input Objects.

```js
[ {id: '#codigoItem0'}, {id: '#codigoItem1'}, {id: '#codigoItem2'} ]
```

2. Use a forEach loop to apply the change event listener to each individual node.

```js
var JSONObj =  [ {id: '#codigoItem0'}, {id: '#codigoItem1'}, {id: '#codigoItem2'} ]

JSONObj.forEach(function(input) {
  var id = input.id;

  $(id).change(function(e) {
    $.post('mandaDescricao.php',
      {
         descricao: document.getElementById(id).value
      },

      function(data){
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        $(id).val(obj.codigo); 

      });
    });  
  })
})
```

Might be worth making a more detailed JSON Array of inputs where an input-Object might look like :

```js
{
  id: 'inputID',
  name: 'inputName'
  val: 'Foo',
  placeholder: 'Bar',
  callback: '_aCallbackMethod()'
}
```

And then you can create input elements based on an Array of those detailed inputs and handle them as Objects rather than needing to query the DOM so much with $(blah). :-)

Comment: I like how you approached this, very systematically. Still it does need to execute only when the user adds a new input to the page as stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks & true - I need to work on reading the query to the fullest before answering. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the ID (which will help with your dynamic problem) You can add the event to all inputs with a class and then use `this` inside the input change event for the input the user is interacting with, for example

```
<input class="descricaoItem" />
<input class="descricaoItem" />
<input class="descricaoItem" />
<input class="descricaoItem" />
<input class="descricaoItem" />

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.descricaoItem').on("input", function() {
    var descricaoValue = $(this).val();
    var self = this; // save context of this
    $.post('mandaDescricao.php', {
        descricao: descricaoValue
      },
      function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        $(self).val(obj.codigo);
      });
  });
});
```

Here is a minimal example (without the POST request)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.descricaoItem').on("input", function() {
    var descricaoValue = $(this).val();
    var self = this; // save context of this
    $(self).val("codigo obj: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="descricaoItem" />
<input class="descricaoItem" />
<input class="descricaoItem" />
<input class="descricaoItem" />
<input class="descricaoItem" />
```